# How to get Asp.Net Core to return the correct view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes

My Asp.Net Core project is arranged as follows:

```
MyApp
--Folder1
  Folder1Controller.cs
  Index.cshtml
--Folder2
  Folder2Controller.cs
  Index.cshtml
--Views
  Shared
  etc..
```

I've changed the startup, so that it's aware of this directory structure:

```
services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ViewLocationFormats.Clear();
    options.ViewLocationFormats.Add($"/Folder1/{{0}}{RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension}");
    options.ViewLocationFormats.Add($"/Folder2/{{0}}{RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension}");
    options.ViewLocationFormats.Add($"/Views/Shared/{{0}}{RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension}");
});
```

The code for the `Folder1Controller` looks like this:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{            
    return View();
}
```

And it works fine.  However, the code for `Folder2Controller` looks exactly the same. The problem is that when it executes the `Index()` method for `Folder2` it looks in `Folder1` first.  I can get around it by doing this:

```
public IActionResult Index(string id)
{
    return View("/Folder2/Index.cshtml");
}
```

My question is, is there a way to get Asp.Net Core to look in the current directory first? Even if I use a relative path (`"./Index"`), it still goes to `Folder1` first.

Comment: The source location of Controllers doesn't map to uri paths. The closest feature might be Area's.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a folder named with controller name to your folder1,folder2,so that route can recognize which view to find.

Firstly,change the folder structure like this:

```
MyApp
--Folder1
  Folder1Controller.cs
  --Folder1
    Index.cshtml
--Folder2
  Folder2Controller.cs
  --Folder2
    Index.cshtml
--Views
  Shared
  etc..
```

Startup:

```
  services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
                {
                    options.ViewLocationFormats.Clear();
                    options.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/Folder1/{1}/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
                    options.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/Folder2/{1}/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
                    options.ViewLocationFormats.Add($"/Views/Shared/{{0}}{RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension}");
                });
```

result:
[image]